# One transaction per request - servlet response is committed too early

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, transactions, spring-boot

i'm trying to implement one transaction per request in my spring boot application.
I have a filter with HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE order that opens a transaction, lets other filters and the app's services do their job and commits the transaction. However, if commit fails, the servlet response has already been written and committed (with a success code), i can't modify it's status and message body to provide info about the error.

I need the servlet response to be modifiable in my filter, but something commits it.

I've disabled jackson commits, but right after the last filter (WsFilter) the message is commited anyway. The buffer size is as big as possible. I guess the embedded tomcat commits by default after WsFilter?

I've also tried using a wrapper and forbidding flush until a Boolean flag is set to true in my transaction filter, but null pointer exception occurres - coyoteResponse is null.

How do i keep a response uncommitted?

Comment: You need to ensure nothing is  written to ServletResponse before all commits have succeeded

Comment: Share the wrapper code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using ContentCachingResponseWrapper. This way all filters after my transaction filter use the wrapper instead of the original response. Since the original response is untouched it is not commited. After my filter close the transaction i call responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse() to "flush" all data from the wrapper to the original response.

in general the code looks like this:

```
// create a transaction
// create a wrapper
chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
// end the transaction
responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
```